# thread pool creation in .net(C#)

Tags: c#

when does the thread pool is created? it is during the creation of the process or the first element is queued in the pool

Answer (score 2):

> When the CLR initializes, its thread
>   pool contains no threads. When the
>   application wants to create a thread
>   to perform a task, the application
>   should request the task be performed
>   by a thread pool thread. The thread
>   pool knows that and will create an
>   initial thread. This new thread will
>   go through the same initialization as
>   any other thread; but, when the task
>   is complete, the thread will not
>   destroy itself. Instead, the thread
>   will return to the thread pool in a
>   suspended state. If the application
>   makes another request of the thread
>   pool, then the suspended thread will
>   just wake up and perform the task and
>   a new thread will not be created.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164139.aspx

this is rather a rather good introduction too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx#threadpool_topic11

Comment: The CLR has a single pool. If you want you can implement your own thread pool, but it is easier to use the thread pool provided by the .NET Framework through the ThreadPool class.

Answer (score 0):

A `ThreadPool` is not created, it only has static members ([MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)). You can set the minimum and maximum number of threads that a `ThreadPool` has, and add work items to it, which execute when the ThreadPool has an available thread. So your question doesn't really make sense, I think you need to clarify it.